How to return a plain text response using ATG actors
I have an actor that need to return a plain text response without the JSON structure that ATG normally respond to the caller.
...actor-chain/droplet code...
<output name="exampleField" value="${myExampleDroplet.exampleParam}" />

...actor-chain/droplet code...
with this output ATG will return something like this:
{ "exampleField":"exampleValue" }
all I want is to return te plain value of the 'exampleParam' without any format, like this:
exampleValue
is that possible with actors on ATG or its needed something else?
tried to use 'add-map-children' but as it is a simple text that need to be returned and not a Map, it is not accepted, reviewed the documentation and did not found anything that helps.

Haven't used the platform for a long time, but isn't there some short of response generator class that could be extended and used by a specific actor?
